# systemctl hibernate gives error not enough swap space for hibernation although the swap space in use is four times the RAM size

Tags: linux, memory, hibernate, kali-linux, systemctl

I already know that in Linux systems `systemctl hibernate` will not allow hibernation if there is not enough swap space for hibernation. But in my case the swap space was set to 32 GiB while the RAM installed was 8 GiB. This error was given when the swap space was not used at all. I want to know why this error is occuring and how can I solve this problem. If it helps, this error occured on Kali Linux (kernel `x86_64 Linux 5.3.0-kali3-amd64`). (I am sorry if this question appears too 'novice like' for a Kali Linux user)

Here is a sample output:

```
# systemctl hibernate
Failed to hibernate system via logind: Not enough swap space for hibernation
# free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8135920     1226892     5975908      254980      933120     6398272
Swap:      33555452           0    33555452
# swapon
NAME       TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/sda10 partition  32G   0B   -2
#
```

Comment: can you show the output of `cat /proc/swaps`